# Extension Delegate with multiple watch version

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit

Is there a way to have ExtensionDelegate with multiple watchOSExtensions? 
My Goal is to have several methods to watchos 3.0 only and a few other methods to watchos 2.0.

Per Xcode 8.6 Beta , the requirements are the following:

- **HKWorkoutConfiguration** is only available on **watchOS 3.0**
- Function **handle** is available starting **watchOS 2.2.0**

Error:

***Protocol 'WKExtensionDelegate' requires 'handle' to be available on watchOS application extension 2.2.0 and newer***

```
import WatchKit
import HealthKit

@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 2.2.0, *)
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {


}//eoc


@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 3.0, *)
extension ExtensionDelegate
{
    @objc(handleWorkoutConfiguration:)
    func handle(_ workoutConfiguration: HKWorkoutConfiguration) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Xcode beta had a brain freeze when it was giving the error.
Closed Xcode beta and open it again and all seems fine. I updated the code to the below and it runs successfully.

```
import WatchKit
import HealthKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        // Perform any final initialization of your application.

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive() {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
    }

    @available(watchOSApplicationExtension 3.0, *)
    func handle( workoutConfiguration: HKWorkoutConfiguration)
    {

    }//eom

}//eoc
```

Comment: Using the Xcode 8 GM seed, I can't get around this.  It is requiring the "handle" method to be implemented in watchOS 2.2, but the HKWorkoutConfiguration argument to that method is only available in watchOS 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

In the watchOS 3.0 GM Seed, the only workaround I could find is to add WK_AVAILABLE_WATCHOS_ONLY(3.0); to the declaration of the handle(_:) method in the WKExtensionDelegate header file. (Clearly a temporary fix; I presume Apple will add this to their headers in the final release.)

Comment: Would you mind posting an example `ExtensionDelegate` objective-c file with this added?  I'm just not that familiar with the syntax, and how to do what you are suggesting.  Thanks!

Comment: In WKExtension.h, change line 51 from 
`- (void)handleWorkoutConfiguration:(HKWorkoutConfiguration *)workoutConfiguration;`
 to 
`- (void)handleWorkoutConfiguration:(HKWorkoutConfiguration *)workoutConfiguration WK_AVAILABLE_WATCHOS_ONLY(3.0);`

Unfortunately it looks like this has not been fixed in the latest release...

Comment: Oh, you mean edit apple's source code?  Didn't realize that was possible.  Figured it was bundled and compiled somewhere.

Comment: Well, really just editing their header files.  (Do command-shift-O in Xcode and search for "WKExtension".) The problem (as far as I can see) is just that the attributes on the declarations are wrong, so that it's requiring that a method be implemented in older watchOS versions, which is impossible because the method takes a parameter that is only available in watchOS 3.